# "Proof" that $\log2=0$ using the expansion of $\log(1+x)$

Tags: logarithms, taylor-expansion, fake-proofs

$$\log(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}{2} +\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^4}{4}\cdots $$
Putting $x=1$ 
$$\log 2=1-\frac12+\frac13-\frac14+\frac15-\frac16+\frac17-\frac18\cdots$$
$$=\left\{\left(1+\frac13+\frac15+\frac17  \cdots\right)-\left(\frac12+\frac14+\frac16 +\frac18 \cdots\right)\right\}$$
$$=\left\{\left(1+\frac13+\frac15+\frac17\cdots\right)+\left(\frac12+\frac14+\frac16 +\frac18\cdots \right)\right\}-2\left(\frac12+\frac14+\frac16 +\frac18 \cdots \right)$$
$$=\left(1+\frac12+\frac13+\frac14+\frac15\cdots\right)-\left(1+\frac12+\frac13+\frac14+\frac15\cdots\right)$$
$$\log 2=0$$
$$2=e^0$$
$$2=1$$
Same result is obtained when I multiplied the $\log2 $expansion by $2$ .

Comment: The expansion of $\log(1+x)$ is valid for $|x|<1$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici it is valid for $x=1$ though.

Comment: To put it more formally, $\sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty} (\frac{1}{2k-1}- \frac{1}{2k}) $.

Since $\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{2k-1}$ and $\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{2k}$,

so the addition is not linear.(i.e. it is invalid to write as$\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{2k-1}-\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{2k}$ )

Comment: You can change the order of summation of a series and get the same result **only** if the series converges absolutely. This is not the case here so you get whatever you want (litereraly) by Riemann's THeorem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, there's one mistake along the way that I have spotted:
$$\cdots=\left\{\left(1+\frac13+\frac15+\frac17\color{red}{+\cdots}\right)-\left(\frac12+\frac14+\frac16 +\frac18\color{red}{+\cdots} \right)\right\}$$

In both of the smaller parenthesis, you have [a variation of the harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#General_harmonic_series), and neither
$$1+\frac13+\frac15+\frac17\color{red}{+\cdots}$$
nor
$$\left(\frac12+\frac14+\frac16 +\frac18\color{red}{+\cdots} \right)$$
converges. You cannot split an infinite sum to two inifinite sums if either of the three infinite sums does not converge.

Answer (score 11):

You may look in [Riemann series theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem) 
The theorem of Riemann says that any conditionally convergent series (yours being the 'classic' example)  may be rearranged to converge to any given number (including $\pm \infty$).

Answer (score 3):

***If***  both series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{2n-1}
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{2n}
$$
are convergent, then also
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}a_n
$$
is convergent and
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}a_n=
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{2n-1}
-
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{2n}
$$
(the proof is not difficult, change sign to the even numbered terms in order to simplify it and get rid of the $(-1)^{n+1}$). There's no requirement for absolute convergence here.

Unfortunately, in your case you ***cannot apply*** this result, because neither the odd-numbered term series nor the even-numbered term series converge.

Answer (score 1):

You assumed that

$\left(\frac12+\frac14+\frac16 +\frac18+\cdots \right)=2 \left(\frac12+\frac14+\frac16 +\frac18+\cdots \right)- \left(\frac12+\frac14+\frac16 +\frac18+\cdots \right)$

Which means

$\infty = 2 \infty - \infty$

You are manipulating infinity and this is the mistake.